# How to end a batch script if another process stops running

Tags: loops, batch-file

I am looking for a way to run my batch script but have it end as soon as another process ends. Is this possible? 
Thanks for any help

Comment: what is your batch file doing while the process is running? what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

```
:check_again

qproc| find /i "myprocess.exe" >nul 2>&1 && (
   goto :check_again
)||(
  exit /b 0
)
```

?